# Synonym needed for [sync] and [synchronization]

Tags: support, synonym-request

The tags [sync](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) and [synchronization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) would seem to be natural synonyms. The shorter version is on more questions, but I much prefer the full name. But, either way, I think one should be a synonym of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created the synonym with [synchronization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) as the master.

They can be swapped over if there's demand for that.

Once we have agreement over which way the synonym should go they can be merged.